# Use a information in other table using phpmyadmin

Tags: jsp, phpmyadmin

how do i use a price per item in *table item* and calculate the items total price to insert in other table which is *table quotation*.

btw, i'm developing a web based using .jsp

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question is Vague , but it may give you an idea.

```
insert into otherTable values (select item * price as totallPrice )
```